# BiometricPrompt faceunlock not works

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-fingerprint-api

I have tried by setup faceunlock on Pixel 2 device,but BiometricPrompt doesnot shows faceunlock dialog,but always shows same fingerprint dialog.
Also BiometricPrompt authenticate method explains,it is only for fingerprint. Still BiometricPrompt not support Faceunlock?

How to implement Faceunlock inside app,if device supports faceunlock,but  below Android P.For example,Samsung S9.

Comment: Biometric prompt only use strong authentication. Which is currently fingerprint only, but in future, it could be better iris and face scanners.

Answer (score 3):

https://source.android.com/security/biometric/

> Android 9 only includes fingerprint integration for BiometricPrompt. However, integrated support for other biometric modalities are forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

The device must support **strong** type of face unlocking. This fulfills Pixel 4 but not Pixel 2 or Pixel 3.

Please see also: [Android Biometrics](https://source.android.com/security/biometric) *All biometric implementations must meet security specifications and have a strong rating in order to participate in the BiometricPrompt class.*